# How can I get HTTP status code using OkHttp when there's no connectivity?

Tags: http, okhttp, http-status-codes

I have the following method:

```java
Response httpResponse = client.newCall(request).execute(); 
httpResponse.code();
```

But in some cases (for example, when I disconnect the phone network, access Google from China or the server is broken), it gives me an `IOException` instead of an error code.

How can I get all the HTTP status code like Volley does?

Comment: There will be no http-status-code in case of a disconnected network or a complete server-breakdown because the statuscode is sent **by the server**.

Comment: thanks, I made a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't get any status code in this situation. Read the [documentation](http://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Call.html#execute--):

> [**`Response execute() throws IOException`**](http://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Call.html#execute--)
>
> Invokes the request immediately, and blocks until the response can be processed or is in error.
>   The caller may read the response body with the response's [`Response.body`](http://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Response.html#body) method. To avoid leaking resources callers must close the response body.
>
> Note that transport-layer success (receiving a HTTP response code, headers and body) does not necessarily indicate application-layer success: response may still indicate an unhappy HTTP response code like `404` or `500`.
>
> **Throws:**
>
> - [`IOException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html): if the request could not be executed due to cancellation, a connectivity problem or timeout. Because networks can fail during an exchange, it is possible that the remote server accepted the request before the failure.
> - [`IllegalStateException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html): when the call has already been executed.

An [`IOException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html) is expected if the request could not be executed due to **a connectivity problem**.